# Execute javascript when all videos on page have been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I have modified this script to accept videos instead of images:

http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

Locally, it works fine, but when I upload to a server, the videos are not synced. The first video starts earlier than the other one. Check it out:

http://amarsyla.com/sandbox/beforeafter/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <video alt="before" autoplay="true" loop="true" width="600" height="366">
            <source src="before.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div>
        <video alt="after" autoplay="true" loop="true" width="600" height="366">
            <source src="after.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

I initialize the plugin using this code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#container').beforeAfter();
});
```

Obviously, the window.load doesn't do the job. I need a JavaScript event or something similar which will be triggered that both of the videos have been loaded and they can start playing simultaneously with each other. I want the videos to be in perfect sync with each other, so each of them starts at the same time, and I thought this would be possible by initializing the plugin after both videos have been fully loaded. I've tried this:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    alert("Can play through video without stopping");
};
```

That doesn't work as I expected. It doesn't always fire. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your own relevant code, specifically how you are starting the videos. You have to control that yourself as the load times will be completely different.

Comment: Both of the videos are plain HTML5 videos, as you can see in the link I provided.

Comment: It may surprise you to know, but we do not want to go drilling into a website to understand what you are doing. Please post just the *relevant* code & html. If you are just injecting HTML5 videos, with no controlling code, then you are out of luck. They will run when they feel like it.

Comment: There's no need for code. If you take a few seconds to read my question, I am only asking for maybe a javascript event or something similar which is triggered when the videos are loaded. I stated that I am using the `<video>` tag.

Comment: If there is no need for code, then you have come to the wrong website. At least show what you have attempted before the down-votes start rolling in.

Comment: To support @TrueBlueAussie. A simple Google trip would give you the events you're looking for!

Comment: @Mouser I could find something but only for one video. I need to check whether both of the videos have been loaded.

Comment: @AmarSyla That's a bit better, look into the `oncanplay`, `oncanplaythrough` and `onloadeddata` events on the video and audio element.

Comment: Okay, I got something in my mind. I can attach the events to each video. Then, e.g. the left video has been loaded, it should update the leftLoaded variable from 0 to 1. The same with right video, which should update the rightLoaded variable from 0 to 1. Then, on another custom function, to check for those two variables every 500ms, and if they both are equal to one, then execute the code.

Comment: As you are using jQuery, a more appropriate solution, rather than polling a counter, is to use `deferred`'s and `promise`'s. Then you get a faster/cleaner response. Up to you of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is different from the code at the link, so I'll go by the latter since that's the one actually running.

It looks like what's happening is that even once the videos are playing, they're losing synchronization a few seconds later when they have to wait for more data from the network. One might think that "oncanplaythrough" would be enough to assume that the videos are sufficiently buffered to play all the way through without pausing, it's not always the case.

In theory, "canplaythrough" fires when the browser guesses that data is coming in faster than you're playing it, as opposed to "canplay" which fires when there is just enough data to show one or two frames from the current time. But Chrome fires "canplaythrough" [immediately](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73609) after "canplay" so you can't count on it. Even on other better-behaved browsers, it's still possible that the data transfer starts fast and then slows down after the event fires.

So that means that you have to continuously watch for any "waiting" events on either video and pause them both until they catch up again.

Here's an example you can use as a reference to get you started:
http://code.chirls.com/whiteknuckles/

It's very old code and not my best work. I would do it differently if I wrote it today, but it seems to work reasonably well.